# Change the WixBundleExecutePackageCacheFolder for Custom Wix Bundle installer

Tags: c#, wix, windows-installer, bootstrapper, burn

I have a custom wixtoolset 3.10.2 bundle that installs 8 different .msi packages. I need to have the extraction/cache folder for the bundle be a folder different than the the standard "C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\Temp".  Is this possible?  I need to do this because we are not allowing any executable to run from this standard temp folder for security reasons.  I would like the cache folder to be something like "C:\MyCompany\Install\Temp" That way I can 'whitelist' that folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can [redirect the package cache](http://wixtoolset.org/development/wips/4278-allow-administrators-and-users-to-redefine-the-payload-cache-locations/) but you cannot change where Burn extracts the BA from the bundle for use during initialization.

Comment: Thank you very much for the fast response and the very clear No answer. Is there a reason why this is not a feature?  We are thinking about trying to make a WiX Improvement Proposal if we cannot figure out how to get around the security issue.

Comment: Probably because nobody's wanted it before.

Comment: Burn uses the %TEMP% environment variable, which the user can change to whatever they want. This is the standard location in Windows for temporary files so people would complain if we started using a different location. I could see this being able to be set on the command line, maybe even from the BA, but not hardcoded in the bundle.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the help. I marked this as the answer. We will explore other options including white-listing in the %Temp% folder by name and by cert signed software.

Answer (score 0):

As part of the work done for [#5830](https://github.com/wixtoolset/issues/issues/5830) and [#5856](https://github.com/wixtoolset/issues/issues/5856) in v4, Burn can have separate locations for the extraction folder (where the clean room process and the elevated process will start from) and the acquisition folder (where payloads are copied/downloaded to before moving to the Package Cache folder). Note that none of these are `WixBundleExecutePackageCacheFolder`, which is a dynamic value that indicates where a specific package is currently executing from.

The acquisition folder is still not configurable and uses `%TEMP%`. Burn should not execute files from here so that should be sufficient.

The extraction folder still defaults to `%TEMP%` but can be overridden on the command line (`-burn.working.directory=<path>`) or in the registry (`EngineWorkingDirectory` in `HKLM\Software\Policies\WiX\Burn`).